# Getting an Error 91 inconsistently: Object variable or With block variable not set - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 16 macro modules that essentially do the same, same code and everything, but sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. This is one that does not work:

```
Dim DPIE As Object
Set DPIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With DPIE
    .navigate "http://www.cyclingsimulator.com/team/The_Modern_Timurids"
    .Visible = False
End With

Do While DPIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set DPInfo = DPIE.document.getElementsByClassName("right")(171)
Dim DPValue As String
DPValue = DPInfo.innerHTML

Set RSInfo = DPIE.document.getElementsByClassName("right")(172)
Dim RSValue As String
RSValue = RSInfo.innerHTML

DPIE.Quit
Set DPIE = Nothing
```

This is one that does usually work:

```
Dim DPIE As Object
Set DPIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With DPIE
    .navigate "http://www.cyclingsimulator.com/team/The_Modern_Timurids"
    .Visible = False
End With

Do While DPIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set DPInfo = DPIE.document.getElementsByClassName("right")(51)
Dim DPValue As String
DPValue = DPInfo.innerHTML

Set RSInfo = DPIE.document.getElementsByClassName("right")(52)
Dim RSValue As String
RSValue = RSInfo.innerHTML

DPIE.Quit
Set DPIE = Nothing
```

There are only two numbers that change and I am at a loss what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which specific line is the problem? It's possible the page is not fully rendered, so maybe try adding a short `Wait` after the `DoEvents` loop

Comment: There are only 53 instances of `class="right"` in that page.

Answer (score 0):

> I have about 16 macro modules that essentially do the same, same code and everything...

This is a separate issue but you really should fix that. Write yourself a sub that takes the minor differences as params and just call it. Probably a good idea to only work with one instance of IE at a time too.

```
Set DPInfo = DPIE.document.getElementsByClassName("right")(171)
```

DPInfo is set to Nothing here because there isn't 171 elements in that collection. That's why you get the exception thrown when you try to access the `.innerHTML` property.

```
?len(DPIE.document.getElementsByClassName("right"))
29
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The comment about using parameters really helps, it has been an afwul long time since I have coded something. Regarding the comment about there not being 171 elements in the collection, I think there are? There are at least 208, because he managed to find 207 and 208.